# How to find total quarters between two dates and copy data n-1 number of times?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like the image below, but with a few more fields (the extra fields are basically irrelevant; trying to keep this simple).

[image]

I want to calculate the quarters and Interest*Principal, but the twist is...I need to insert the same number of rows as there are quarters, and copy everything from above, down.

[image]

Basically, due to some weird reporting requirements, I need to insert 12 rows under the 13 (13 rows total) and copy everything down.  Then, insert 7 rows under the 8 (8 rows total) and copy everything down.  The final result needs to look like this.

[image]

```
-- DDL
    CREATE TABLE Reporting_Table (
       ID    varchar(10),
       IssueDate     Date,
       ExpirationDate    Date,
       Principal     Money,
       Interest  Money,
       Qtrs      Integer,
       Calcs     Money)

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Calcs)
VALUES ('1232949523', '01/01/2017', '12/31/2019', 1000000, .02, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Calcs)
VALUES ('9967949523', '03/05/2017', '12/31/2018', 5200000, .01, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Calcs)
VALUES ('1199949523', '03/31/2017', '06/01/2020', 4900000, .015, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Calcs)
VALUES ('9567323294', '06/30/2017', '05/22/2019', 3500000, .02, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Calcs)
VALUES ('0232949593', '09/17/2017', '11/21/2022', 2000000, .02, Null, Null);


SELECT ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, (Principal * Interest) As Calcs
FROM Reporting_Table
```

I think the SQL will look something like this:

```
Select ID,IssueDate,ExpirationDate,Principal,Interest,
    year(ExpirationDate)*4 + ceiling(month(ExpirationDate)/3) - year(IssueDate)*4 - ceiling(month(IssueDate)/3) As Qrts,
    (Principal*Interest) AS Calcs
From Reporting_Table
```

However, it seems like the quarters are off a bit.  Also, I don't know how to inert n-1 number of rows, and copy the data from above down, after the insert is done.  **I am using SQL Server 2008.**

I know the structure is very non-normalized, but the table will be pretty large, so selects should be very fast, and also, this will be fed into a web-based system, which is quite dumb, and won't allow me to present the data as I described above, so I need to accomplish everything in one base-table.  Thanks, experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in several ways using recursive CTE, tally table. This solution uses `master.dbo.spt_values` as tally table. I have changed calculation of column Qrts, check if that works.

```
with cte as (
    Select 
        ID,IssueDate,ExpirationDate,Principal,Interest
        , Qrts = ceiling((datediff(mm, IssueDate, ExpirationDate)) / 3.0)
        , (Principal*Interest) AS Calcs
    From 
        Reporting_Table
)
select
    c.*
from
    cte c
    join master.dbo.spt_values v on c.Qrts > v.number
where
    v.type = 'P'
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes!  I think this will do it.  Thanks.  I knew it was a CTE, but I was never good at those things.  It seems like the sub-query does the same thing as the: with cte...from cte c.  I guess all the magic happens from: join master...'p'.  It's not obvious, to me at least, what that part is doing.

Comment: You are right! I have used CTE just to make it more understandable. `master.dbo.spt_values` multiples each row by the value of `Qrts` field